# Is there a meaningful ITrigger.ToString() method in Quartz?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

What I mean is if I have a trigger like:

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
   .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        .WithIntervalInSeconds(40)
        .RepeatForever())
   .Build();
```

I want to be able to get meaningful (maybe even localized) description of trigger's schedule. For example, I want to see **"Repeat every 40 seconds."** message when I call `trigger.ToMeaningfulString()`. I couldn't google something like that but I'm almost sure I'm not the first one who got this idea and, maybe, there's already an implementation. This will be useful in case if you want to develop some kind of jobs manager which will display trigger or job status/details. This is not a top priority task so I wouldn't want to invest a lot of effort in it if there's no existed implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it exists for simple schedules. If you build your schedule using cron expressions, however, you could use [cron expression descriptor](https://github.com/bradyholt/cron-expression-descriptor), which takes a cron expression and does exactly what you ask for:

```
var cronExpression = "40 * * * * ?";
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithCronSchedule(cronExpression)
        .Build();

var humanReadableString = ExpressionDescriptor.GetDescription(cronExpression);
// humanReadableString = "Every 40 seconds"
```

Available as [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CronExpressionDescriptor/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this later, but I think this could be exactly what I was looking for.